# Render network images and maintain aspect ratio for height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image

**React-native: 0.47.1**

How would I maintain the aspect ratio for height when the width is 100%? Basically I want to auto scale the height while maintaining the aspect ratio. The images will be displayed in a `FlatList` (not necessarily, if something else worls I'm happy to change the `FlatList`). Images are displayed from an array of `data` which is set in the `state`:

```
export default class ImageTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data : [
        {id: 1, name: "image1", url: "http://urlOfImage.com/1.jpg"}
        {id: 2, name: "image2", url: "http://urlOfImage.com/2.jpg"}
        {id: 3, name: "image3", url: "http://urlOfImage.com/3.jpg"}
        {id: 4, name: "image4", url: "http://urlOfImage.com/4.jpg"}
        {id: 5, name: "image5", url: "http://urlOfImage.com/5.jpg"}
      ];
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem = {({item})=> 
               <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
               <Image 
                   source={uri: item.url}
                   style={styles.myImageStyle} />
            }
        />
    </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  myImageStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: /* WHAT DO I PUT HERE ?? */
  }
)
```

So the images may vary in height, original height may be 700px, some maybe 1200px, or even a square image. How would I define the height for each image since they're coming from an array?

Many thanks

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a dimensions of the image from URI. You can loop through your array and take the dimensions for each image using static method `getSize()` included in `Image` component. Here is a [documentation for this method](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize)

Example:

```
const preloadedImgData = []
this.state.data.forEach((img) => {
   Image.getSize(img.url, (w, h) => {
      img.dimensions = {w, h}
      preloadedImgData.push(img)
   })
})
```

*I'm not sure if above code is 100% correct but you got the idea :)*

EDIT:

Also you can use this module which should do everything for you: [react-native-fit-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fit-image)

*- I'm not owner of this module*

Comment: It works! The `fit-image` module did the trick. I'm going to explore it and see how they made it work. It doesn't work on local images as of now but it's marvelous! Thanks a ton. I actually had a brief look at it and skipped it as the first example stated to mention the dimensions beforehand. I should've tested it. Thanks again mate. cheers!!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fit-image works like a charm...